# How to generate only one underlying YUV layer on Android?

Tags: android, layer

I wrote an Android app to display full-screen YUV layer through a full-screen video playing using VideoView Component. Only the video playing window can be seen on the screen, I thought there should be only one underlying layer. But using "dumpsys SurfaceFlinger" shell command can see 2 layers: one is SurfaceView(YUV format); and another is a RGB layer.

My questions are:

1) why is there a RGB layer?

2) How to generate only one underlying YUV layer on Android?

Comment: Is this RGB layer the app UI layer, or an *additional* RGB layer?  (Can you paste the HWC summary portion of the dumpsys output in your question?)

Comment: It's an additional RGB layer.

Comment: I didn't expect there's the 2nd layer. Below is dumpsys infor:numHwLayers=2, flags=00000000
    HWC_2D | b7cb0620 | 00000000 | 00000000 | 00 | 00100 | 0000002a | [      0,      0,    640,    480] | [    0,    0,  720, 1280] SurfaceView
    HWC_2D | b7cc18a8 | 00000000 | 00000000 | 00 | 00105 | 00000005 | [      0,      0,    720,     28] | [    0,    0,  720,   28] com.example.fullscreentest/com.example.fullscreentest.yuvActivity